# Word document to PDF: open hyperlinks in new window

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, export, adobe-acrobat

I have a Microsoft Word document with hyperlinks in it. When I save it as a PDF document, those hyperlinks no longer open that link in a new window. I have tried all the settings under the "*Target Frame...*" option, but those don't seem to persist.

Is there any settings that help with this to make all hyperlinks in the document open in a new window?

I am currently using the Acrobat plugin, but could move to a different plugin if it offers this feature.

**Clarification:**

I am using Word 2007

I can create PDFs using plugins for word (either the Acrobat plugin or the Microsoft PDf/XPS plugin). The problem exists after that.

So here is my scenario:

Once I create a PDF, I place it up on a website for users to view. This PDF has additional links to other websites for more information. Once a user pulls up my PDF, its embedded inside the browser. The problem arises when a person clicks on one of these links and gets transferred to a different website. Some people have problems clicking the back button getting back to the PDF. So I am looking for a way for those links embedded inside the PDF to open inside a new window, just like one would do with an HTML page.

Google does not turn up anything expect a lot of dead ends and/or this can't be done, which very well may be the case, was just hoping for a better solution.

Comment: What options does that "target frame" give you? For HTML, only `_blank` (including the leading underscore) would be appropriate. Anything else might open a new window for the first click, but then also name that window with that target-name. Hence, subsequent clicks would re-use that same window.

Comment: And maybe to see if it's really a PDF-generation problem, rather than a browser or browser plugin problem: what if you test with a PDF exported from OpenOffice.org? Or test using a different browser? Or test by actually downloading the file first?

Comment: I have tried all the options now in word 2007 & Open Office. I basically want to replicate the "_blank" option given in straight HTML code, yet I can't figure out how to replicate this with links inside a PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if you go into Edit > Preferences > Documents and then uncheck "Open cross-document links in same window" that it will then open the links in a new window.  It was driving me crazy too.

Comment: Must be a new addition into the PDF reader, but that did the trick!

Comment: That only works if the viewer happens to be using Adobe Reader plugin in their browser, *and* also changed this setting. In other words, it only changes how you view the PDF on your side. It doesn't change the way the Word doc is converted to PDF or the final PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Download and install Microsoft's official plugin to save documents as PDF:

[2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en)

After it's installed, you can save your Word document as PDF, and have your hyperlinks clickable on the PDF document. I've tested it and it works. Trust me ;)

<sub>By the way, I assume that you are using MS Word 2007. This plugin is just for MS Office 2007.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the plugin! Seems a heck of a lot simpler to use. However, this did not solve the problem :(. Please read my clarification.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the link in Word, you must edit the target frame:  Make link in Word, right click, add hyperlink.  Then new dialogue pops open.  On the right, you will see "Target Frame."  Click this and choose the correct option from the drop down menu.  Voila!

Comment: I've tried all those options, and none of them work the same way in the exported PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while clicking the hyperlink the linked document will open in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

http://try67.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/convert-all-links-in-pdf-to-open-in-new.html

I searched all over the internet and nobody had a good solution.

Finally stumbled upon this program and it was exactly what I needed to open links in new tab/window. They also have a demo version so you can see how it works.

Comment: This cost $99 per license.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer as well for Microsoft Word 2013. There is a button on the HyperLink dialogue box that says Target Frame and you can choose a new window. However, when it is converted to PDF, it does not work.

If the reader uses the CTRL key, it opens in a new window. I also found it opens in a new window using the CTRL key no matter what. You may have to put in your document to use the CTRL key and let it go from there. That is going to be my solution.