# PDF - Open hyperlinks in new window

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, export, microsoft-word-2016

In Microsoft Word (2016), when we create Hyperlinks, we can give the Target frame as New Window. Then every time we click on it, it will open the URL in the new window.

[image: Screenshot]

However, after we export the word file to a PDF file, those hyperlinks target frame functions will stop working. It will work as a URL, but when you click on it, it will not open in a new Window. It will open in the same window. (Assuming you open PDF using a Web browser.)

How can I fix this?
How can I make a PDF that will open hyperlinks in new Windows using Microsoft Word? (or any other tool) Is there a setting that helps me to do this..?

Update (April 10, 2019)
I know that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to open hyperlinks in new windows. But that's not what I'm looking for.

-Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word document to PDF: open hyperlinks in new window](https://superuser.com/questions/135618/word-document-to-pdf-open-hyperlinks-in-new-window)

Comment: @browly, it's the same question. The only difference is the Microsoft office version. However, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39762965/6327676